# problem relating two tables for get same id mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems to relate the columns of two tables

this is my table1 structure

where I want to relate the identify column to the id of table 2
[image: this is my table1 structure]

this is my table2 structure

[image: this is my table2 structure]

this is my query

```
$id             = (!empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0);
    $example1       = (!empty($_REQUEST['example1']) ? $_REQUEST['example1'] : '');
    $example2 = (!empty($_REQUEST['example2']) ? $_REQUEST['example2'] : '');
    $consult  = "SELECT a.id, a.user, a.date, a.action
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b on b.idwork = $id
    WHERE module = 'Activity ".$idexample1."|".$idexample2."' AND identifier = $id ORDER BY id DESC ";
```

I get this after run my query

```
SELECT a.id, a.user, a.date, a.action 
        FROM table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b on b.id = 244
        WHERE module = 'activity 1|98' AND identificador = 244 ORDER BY id DESC
```

what I try is to relate and make is that $id be the same identifier number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join should be based `ON` the equality of the columns `b.id` and    `a.identifier`:

```
SELECT a.id, a.user, a.date, a.action 
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b 
ON b.id = a.identifier
WHERE a.module = 'activity 1|98' AND b.idwork = 244 
ORDER BY a.identifier DESC
```

I used also the `WHERE` clause from your code and changed the column names to the ones of your sample data.

Comment: its posibble I get this some like this ? WHERE a.module = 'activity 1|98' AND identifier = 47891 ORDER BY a.identifier DESC

Comment: Yes if you want to join the tables for 1 specific value of a.identifier.

Comment: Does my ignorance excuse me as it would be in this case?

Comment: I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: for get some like this its posibble I get this some like this ? WHERE a.module = 'activity 1|98' AND identifier = 47891 ORDER BY a.identifier DESC.  I need change my table structure?

Comment: I don't see a reason to change the structure of your tables. It's a WHERE clause. Use it if this is what you want.

Comment: I keep getting same id 244 and that id not show my dates on my datatable

Comment: 244 is the column idwork from table2 from which you don't select any columns. How do you see it? Even if you select it you should see it because this is the matching row from table2.